# Why do you have to add a classpath when trying to execute a java program from the embedded terminal in intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have just started using Intellij and wanted to run a simple java program from the embedded terminal. I am using Ubuntu

Main.java is located in ~/IdeaProjects/Test0/src/app

From the embedded terminal, after compiling using javac I try.

```
~/IdeaProjects/Test0/src$ java app.Main
```

that results is

```
Error: Could not find or load main class app.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: app.Main
```

This is the code

```
package app;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

But when I execute the same command in the same directory in an actual terminal. The program works just fine.

By using the run button in the intellij ide. It executes the command in the embedded terminal.

```
usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -javaagent:/snap/intellij-idea-community/113/lib/idea_rt.jar=40685:/snap/intellij-idea-community/113/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/user/IdeaProjects/Test0/out/production/Test0 app.Main
```

And this works just fine.

Why does intellij need to declare the classpath in order to work? Why couldn't it execute using `java app.Main`?

Answer (score 0):

Let me take assume that the original problem that needs solving is simply running your code. 
IntelliJ is an IDE and one of the problems it solves is for you to no longer have to run your code from the command line.

You can import and run your code by:

1. Click File / Open
2. Browse your Main.java in your project folder
3. Right click on the Main file
4. Select Run Main.main()

And you can see the results in the Run frame that pops up at the bottom of the IDE.
From now on you can re-run the same by clicking the green play button on the top-right section on your screen.

[Here is a playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c0efB_CKOYo&list=PLPZy-hmwOdEXdOtXdFzyx_XCnrF_oD2Ft) for learning more.